# Foreach for database

Tags: php, database

So I have the following code:

```
<?php
$post_id = 1;   
$name_result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM rh_names WHERE post_id = '$post_id' ");
?>
<?php if (!empty($name_result)) { ?>        
  <?php foreach ($name_result as $names) {?>        
    <div class="names">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var nameXML = <?php echo json_encode($names); ?>;
            document.write(nameXML.last_name);
        </script>
    </div>
   <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

In the database, I have two results that should show up, but I am only getting one.

Why am I only getting one result when two should show up? What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. Use `var_dump($name_result);` to check the actual result. Make sure you are looking at the correct database and not a development instance.

Comment: you should encode as json the `$name_result` array. `$names` will contain each single item and will be overwritten each time you loop an item of the `$name_result` array

Comment: `$jsonEncoded = json_encode($names);
echo $jsonEncoded;`

Answer (score -1):

document.write will replace all document element so you can see last result only try

```
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = res_content;
```

Comment: No, it won't replace all.

Comment: if he is saying then his result may be right and nothing is wrong in code :(